# iPhone : UINavigation Controller within a view displaying another view

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I think I am having a case of disappearing up my own arse.

I am creating a small view on a ipad thats for settings (so not full scree), within this view. I need a navigation controller to show another view.

At the moment I have one class / xib

The xib contains the main view (graphic / boarder).  This view is linked to the files owner and appear.
On the same xib, I also have a navigation controller that contains the inner view.

OnViewDidLoad I add the navigationcontroller.view to the subview and it appears. However I cant push anything off it.  I wired up the delegate and etc but I am sure I am missing something stupid

Can I do this all within one controller / xib?

The only code I have done is

```
[self.view addSubview:mainNavigationController.view];
```

Is there some code I need to do for the navigationController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding the navigation controller as a subview doesn't hook up the navigation controller to the view controller hierarchy properly. That's probably why it doesn't work.

Also the properties that need to be set are readonly properties, so I don't think there's anything you can really do about it.

Comment: @Burf2000 I suppose you could write your own navigation controller, but it's not a trivial task and far beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: So basically I shoudl split this in to 2 viewcontrollers, 1 for the nav and 1 for the view